# unable to create calendar element inside promises success

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I want to use calender element inside the promises 's "then" block , i have a dynamic data and want to use it in calander attribute but the main problem i am facing is that calander is not generated when used inside the promises . when i use it ourside its work(for static values) . I don't know  what is the problem .
for initial purpose i am using static value for calander in promise . but still i am not getting what is the problem .

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url();?>/MyController/ajax_cal',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:function(results) {
                resolve(results); 
                //reject(Error(request.statusText)); // status is not 200 O K, so reject
            }
        });
  });
promise.then(function(data) {
      alert(data.id);   // get the data from promises 

      // calander is not generated BUT work when use outside the then block
          <!-- Calander Module starts-->
    var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar({
            events_source: [
                {
                    "id": '123',
                    "title": 'Hello World',
                    "url": '#',
                    "class": 'event-success',
                    "start": '1362938400000',
                    "end": '1363197686300' // Milliseconds
                }

            ],
            view: 'month',
            tmpl_path: '<?php echo base_url();?>asserts/bootstrap_calender/tmpls/',
            tmpl_cache: false,
            day: '2017-03-15',
            onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
                if(!events) {
                    return;
                }
                var list = $('#eventlist');
                list.html('');

                $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                    $(document.createElement('li'))
                        .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                        .appendTo(list);
                });
            },
            onAfterViewLoad: function(view) {
                $('.page-header h3').text(this.getTitle());
                $('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');
                $('button[data-calendar-view="' + view + '"]').addClass('active');
            },
            classes: {
                months: {
                    general: 'label'
                }
            }
    }); 
    (function($) {
    $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.click(function() {
                calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
            });
        });

        $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.click(function() {
                calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
            });
        });

        $('#first_day').change(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            value = value.length ? parseInt(value) : null;
            calendar.setOptions({first_day: value});
            calendar.view();
        });

        $('#language').change(function(){
            calendar.setLanguage($(this).val());
            calendar.view();
        });

        $('#events-in-modal').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : null;
            calendar.setOptions({modal: val});
        });
        $('#format-12-hours').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
            calendar.setOptions({format12: val});
            calendar.view();
        });
        $('#show_wbn').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
            calendar.setOptions({display_week_numbers: val});
            calendar.view();
        });
        $('#show_wb').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
            calendar.setOptions({weekbox: val});
            calendar.view();
        });
        $('#events-modal .modal-header, #events-modal .modal-footer').click(function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            //e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }(jQuery)); 

    <!-- Calander Module ends-->

}, function(error) {
    console.log('Promise rejected.');
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

Comment: so, erm, what is the variable `promise`? where does it come from? what is it? do you get any errors in your browser **developer** tools console at all?

Comment: i have define it ... i am getting correct value in alert in promises then

Comment: so ... add some debugging to your .then code, see where it fails ... if you can't share how `promise` is created, then the answer to your problem is a pineapple

Comment: So. Are there any errors in the console or not?

Comment: By the way. JQuery ajax already returns a promise so you should avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: @JaromandaX i am need to java script can you help me with the solution . what should i do

Comment: You can start by telling me if there are any errors in the developer tools console

Comment: @JaromandaX . Console error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).calendar is not a function
    at MyController:243

Comment: right ... so you've loaded jquery, but have you loaded whatever plugin gives you `.calendar`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Its working when placed our side the promises then block .   this code in in my view section . do i need to call it again in my controller (MVC : codeigniter)

Comment: @JaromandaX . i am using codigniter